# Embedded Google Analytics API but not showing property and views and other data

Tags: python, django, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have embedded google analytics API using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started. I am testing it on localhost, I have successfully embedded the GA API but it is not populating any data.

[image: plz check the image]

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo I solved it, property and view bars are now populated.